# Type mismatch error when running a macro and the sheet has specific code

Tags: vba, excel

My Program: I have a program that imports data and splits it up into different sheets within the same workbook. Once the data has been split the purpose is for the end user to be able to go into those sheets and update the data. If the user updates the data, that specific cell will change colors. So I have created a code specifically for those sheets to automatically update when the end user enters the data.

My Problem: The split macro works perfectly on its own, the specific sheet code works perfectly on its own. However, when I go to run the whole program together - vba proceeds a typed mismatched error.

This is the specific sheet code

```
 Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Target.Select
    Range("E" & ActiveCell.Row).Select
    ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 24

    If Target.Value < 2000000 Then      'ERROR OCCURS HERE WHEN I CLICK MY SPLIT BUTTON
        If Target.Column = 16 Then
            Range("R" & Target.Row) = "Low"
        End If
    End If

    If Target.Value >= 2000000 And Target.Value < 10000000 Then
        If Target.Column = 16 Then
            Range("R" & Target.Row) = "Medium"
        End If
    End If

    If Target.Value >= 10000000 Then
        If Target.Column = 16 Then
            Range("R" & Target.Row) = "High"
        End If
    End If

    If Target.Value < 600000 Then
        If Target.Column = 17 Then
            Range("R" & Target.Row) = "Low"
        End If
    End If

    If Target.Value >= 600000 And Target.Value < 3000000 Then
        If Target.Column = 17 Then
            Range("R" & Target.Row) = "Medium"
        End If
    End If

    If Target.Value >= 3000000 Then
        If Target.Column = 17 Then
            Range("R" & Target.Row) = "High"
        End If
    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you checked that the cell 'Target' is formatted as a number and not a string?

Comment: Yes I have, and the issue comes at the first target select as well

Comment: It is not necessary to select the ```Target``` nor the range where you want to change the ```Interior.ColorIndex```. Try to replace the three lines of code after ```Application.EnableEvents = False``` with ```Range("E" & Target.Row).Interior.ColorIndex = 24```.

Comment: @dee THANK YOU! i just realized that and it worked!

Comment: you have to be sure `target.value` is a number , so, before all others `if`, add a simple `if Isnumeric(Target.value) then `

Answer (score 0):

Good programming practice states: if some piece of code reapeats at least two times, move it into separate procedure/function.

Playing with Excel VBA, to not ever use **Select** statement, unless it's necessary.

Improved procedure could look like:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Range("E" & Target.Row).Interior.ColorIndex = 24
    Range("R" & Target.Row) = GetStatus(Target.Value)

    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Function GetStatus(ByVal curVal As Integer, ByVal iCol As Integer) As String
Dim sRetVal As String

Select Case iCol
    Case 16
        Select Case curVal
            Case Is < 2000000
                sRetVal = "Low"
            Case 2000000 To 10000000
                sRetVal = "Medium"
            Case Is >= 10000000
                sRetVal = "High"
        End Select
    Case 17
        Select Case curVal
            Case Is < 600000
                sRetVal = "Low"

            Case 600000 To 299999.9999
                    sRetVal = "Medium"

            Case Is >= 3000000
                sRetVal = "High"
        End Select
End Select

End Function
```

But, why to force doors wide open? Use [conditional formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb226688%28v=office.11%29.aspx).

Cheers,
Maciej